# How to put image with description with Firebase and next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

i'am using firebase 9 and next.js 13 to make crud app and i want to make "post" with image in it, but seems like the image didn't follow the post id, and how do i display the image in other components ? because i have separate "post" and "blog" components. the image successfully store in firebase and shown at "post" components

Here is my code:

```
 const [post, setPost] = useState({ description: "" });
  const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [imageUpload, setImageUpload] = useState(null);
  const [imageList, setImageList] = useState([]);
  const route = useRouter();

  const imageListRef = ref(storage, "posts/");
  const routeData = route.query;

  //Post
  const submitPost = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

      //Make new post
      const collectionRef = collection(db, "posts");
      await addDoc(collectionRef, {
        ...post,
        timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
        user: user.uid,
        avatar: user.photoURL,
        username: user.displayName,
      }).then((document) => {
        //Upload Image
        if (imageUpload) {
          const imageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${imageUpload.name + v4()}`);
          uploadBytes(imageRef, imageUpload).then((snaphot) => {
            getDownloadURL(snaphot.ref).then((url) => {
              setImageList((prev) => [...prev, url]);
            });
          });
        }
      });
      setPost({ description: "" });

      return route.push("/Dashboard/Blog");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkUser();
    listAll(imageListRef).then((response) => {
      response.items.forEach((item) => {
        getDownloadURL(item).then((url) => {
          setImageList((prev) => [...prev, url]);
        });
      });
    });
  }, [user, loading]);
```

```
<form onSubmit={submitPost}>
          <textarea
            value={post.description}
            onChange={(e) => setPost({ ...post, description: e.target.value })>
</textarea>
          <input
            type="file"
            onChange={(event) => {
              setImageUpload(event.target.files[0]);
            }}
            className="text-sm "
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="bg-primary-green w-full font-semibold p-2 my-2 rounded-md"
          >
            Upload
          </button>
          {imageList.map((url) => {
            return <img src={url} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </form>
```

i tried few solution but still not work, Any help will be really appreciated i'am just a beginer

and here is the Message component that contain "post" that will be display in "Blog" component, i want image that i store in it

```
export default function Message({ children, avatar, username, description }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <img src={avatar}/>
        <div>
          <h2 >{username}</h2>
          <p >7:20 PM · Jan 19, 2023</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>{description}</p>
      </div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you must use context or global state management libraries like Redux.

Comment: Okay that for pass the image to other commponents, but how to attach image to the post ?